# Binary categorial classification of customer journey

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, binary, classification, categorical-data

I would like to develop a model which can classify the binary nature of customer journey (1 signifies that the journey was completed with a purchase and 0 with no purchase ("jrn_type" column). The journey is composed by channels, as shown in the image of the data below (columns from 1 to 7).

[image]

Which model would fit best the data?

Comment: Seems like you have lots of `nan` values in last four columns, is this same for all the data-set. For selection of model, there is no `golden-rule`, but you can try with very simple model like `regression`, `naive-bayes` at first, if they can solve your problem, then move to another model.

Comment: yes I have a lot of `nan` because there is a different number of channels for each journey and the null value represents the journey is terminated. I consider the `nan` to be an additional class to my channels' classes.

Comment: I doubt, if that work, beacuse then it will cause biasing in your model, but you can give a try.

Comment: How would you approach it? Any idea?

Comment: Actually it is difficult to guess without understanding the complete problem.

Comment: So, for instance,  it can be that one journey is composed by 10 different channels and another by just 3. In oder to include both of them in my model, I replace the missing channels of the second journey with `nan`.

Comment: In general , the `nan` class is a solution for the feature vectors of variable length.

Comment: Emanuela, your approach may be right, give it a try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naive Bayes is a simple, yet effective and commonly-used, machine learning classifier. It is a probabilistic classifier that makes classifications using the Maximum A Posterior decision rule in a Bayesian setting. According to your data, you would better use Naive Bayes model.
Logistic Regression is always a good standby and Decision tree will classify your data, but not as well as Naive Bayes.
In the end, i recommend you to validate your model with a cross-validation method to be sure that you have learned the model well.

Comment: Hi, I tried out with different classifiers and, as you suggested, the best accuracy on the features' test set has been reached by the Naive Bayes with an accuracy of 74%. How can I improve my accuracy with this type of classifier?